# crontab won't query Python MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, cron, lamp

I connect to mysql in Python with a library called MySQLdb, that runs fine from terminal.
When I reboot and let crontab run the same file, no values are entered into the database.

PHP has no problems connecting.

python file looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import time
import datetime
import os

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys; sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/')
import MySQLdb as mdb

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

sensor = ['/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000059ff0ae',
  '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000005a0218e',
  '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000005a0486f',
  '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000005a10dc2',
  '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-000005a13c68']

def read_temp_raw(fil):
  f = open(sensor[fil]+'/w1_slave', 'r')
  lines = f.readlines()
  f.close()
  return lines

def read_temp(fil):
  lines = read_temp_raw(fil)
  while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
      time.sleep(0.2)
      lines = read_temp_raw()
  equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
  if equals_pos != -1:
      temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
      temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
      return temp_c

def tryInsert(col,val):
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO temps("+col+") VALUES"+str(val))
  con.commit()

tid = str(int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())))

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'something', 'temp')
cur = con.cursor()
tryInsert("time,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5",str((tid,read_temp(0),read_temp(1),read_temp(2),read_t    emp(3),read_temp(4))))

con.close()
```

In mysql log I can see that it connects every minute, but not querying.
So crontab executes the python file.

```
141120 18:04:02    47 Connect   root@localhost on temp
       47 Query set autocommit=0
       47 Quit  
141120 18:05:01    48 Connect   root@localhost on temp
       48 Query set autocommit=0
       48 Quit  
141120 18:06:01    49 Connect   root@localhost on temp
       49 Query set autocommit=0
       49 Quit  
141120 18:07:01    50 Connect   root@localhost on temp
       50 Query set autocommit=0
       50 Quit
```

Syslog looks like this:

```
Nov 20 19:17:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2894]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Nov 20 19:18:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2910]: (root) CMD (cd /home/ && python tempsensor.py &)
Nov 20 19:19:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2924]: (root) CMD (cd /home/ && python tempsensor.py &)
Nov 20 19:20:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2931]: (root) CMD (cd /home/ && python tempsensor.py &)
Nov 20 19:21:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2949]: (root) CMD (cd /home/ && python tempsensor.py &)
Nov 20 19:22:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[2957]: (root) CMD (cd /home/ && python tempsensor.py &)
```

if I run the pythonfile from terminal, mysql log looks like this.

```
141120 18:57:06    72 Query INSERT INTO temps(time,temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5)   VALUES('1416506222', 23.0, 22.75, 23.0, 22.812, 23.0)
       72 Query commit
       72 Quit
```

Crontab file looks like this

```
* * * * * cd /home/ && python tempsensor.py &
```

hosts file looks like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1         localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0     ip6-localnet
ff00::0     ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1     ip6-allnodes
ff02::2     ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1   raspberrypi
```

I set the pythonfiles permissions to 7777 just to eliminate that issue.
I have searched similar questions, and did what solved the problem for them, but no luck here.
So what do I miss here?

Comment: What does your python code look like?

Comment: Try connecting and creating the cursor just before the call to tryInsert and see if a connection is being made to MySQL

Comment: @spicavigo I tried that now, still no luck. I updated python file in the question, so it matches that. And added mysql log, when I run the .py file from terminal.

Comment: Another thing that can help debug is to get the output of cron in a file and see if anything interesting pops up there

Comment: @spicavigo I added the syslog. I do not see anything interesting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to change 
`* * * * * cd /home/ && python tempsensor.py &` 
to 
`* * * * * cd /home/ && sudo python tempsensor.py &`